# ERROR: Could not detect Ninja v1.8.2 or newer - Meson

Tags: compiler-errors, ninja, meson-build

When I try to run Meson, It complains that it can't find Ninja v1.8.2 or newer. I ran this:

```
meson build-debug
```

This resulted in the error explained above. I have the latest tools:

Ninja v1.10.2

Meson 0.61.2

x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling `ninja` (v1.10.2.3) via pip fixed this for me (Arch Linux, Meson 0.61.2).
Simply execute the following code in your command line (e.g., `Bash`)

```bash
pip3 install --force-reinstall ninja
```

Comment: I am getting errors like ' meson-python: error: Could not find ninja version 1.8.2 or newer', any help